# Error Retrieving object from aws s3 and displaying the object in Webpage in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, iframe

I am building a chatpdf app in which i want to display the pdf on my browser which are stored as objects in my s3 bucket. When I am using the below code i am not able to display the pdf. I am getting the pdf_url link from s3 int the format :

1. https://myprojectchatpdf.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/uploads/1710527684936hello.pdf

````
 export default function PDFViewer({pdf_url}: PDFViewerProps){

 return (<iframe src={`https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${pdf_url}pdf&embedded=true`} className='w-full h-full'></iframe>);
 }```

But on generating the link of the object from the aws console: presigned_link and using the following code i am able to display the pdf but the link would expire after certain amount of time:


```type PDFViewerProps = {pdf_url: string}
export default function PDFViewer({ pdf_url }: PDFViewerProps) {
    var presigned_url = encodeURIComponent('here pasting the presigned_url...');
    const iframeurl = `https://docs.google.com/gview?url=${presigned_url}&embedded=true`;
    console.log('iframe url: ',iframeurl);
    return <iframe src={iframeurl} title = 'pdf-viewer' className=" w-full h-full"></iframe>;
  }```




Please suggest a method by which i can display the pdf of aws object not using presigned_link , using the 1st link method in react-native or next.js.
````

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is streaming files (in your case, a PDF) from your backend to the client. You could store it in a temporary ObjectURL (which will be valid as long as your browser session is open).

next.js for example

```
  const response = await fetch('/pdf');
  const blob = await response.blob();
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
  // Open the PDF in a new tab
  window.open(url, '_blank');
```